# prooving graph with no cycles and |V | = |E| + 1 is a tree.

Tags: graph-theory, trees

My assignment is to prove that G = (V, E) is a tree if and only if |V | = |E| + 1 and G has no cycles.

However, I am having some trouble doing just that.

We defined a tree as a graph which is connected and doesn't have any cycles so  the no cycles part of the proof is given,right? More specifically I can't figure out how to show that if a graph G = (V, E) has |V | = |E| + 1 and no cycles then it is connected.

Any tips, hints, etc. are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Hint: induction.

Comment: hmm, well. I'm not entirely sure if my logic is sound but could the induction go something like this? it obviously works for a graph with |V |=1 and now we suppose it works for |V |=n and we want to show it works for n+1, right? so if we add a vertex which doesnt make complete a cycle we add an edge and a vertex so |V | = |E| + 1 still stands. and if the previous graph was connected so is the one with the added vertex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with all edges removed. That would give you a graph with $|V|$ connected components. Now add the edges one by one. Each edge you add will reduce the number of connected components by $1$ (since it will connect two previously unconnected components). By the time you get to $|V| - 1$ edges, there is exactly one connected component.

Comment: oh, that makes sense. and if i'm correct we add the edges however we want as long as they don't complete a cycle right?

Comment: @invidia_95 That is correct. Because adding an edge that completes a loop does _not_ decrease the number of connected components, if you do complete a loop you will have more than $|V|-1$ edges once you have a connected graph.